# GWT GChart - Can ticks be positioned with offset?

Tags: java, gwt, gchart

I want to customize a chart developed using GWT library clientsidegchart (gchart) and I want to position the X axis tick labels above the axis and a little to the right (so that they don't overlap with the gridlines). 
How can I do that ?

And also, I tried modifying the tick label font size (to 10 px) but no changes were visible.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a workaround, but `setTickLabelPadding()` with a negative value does the trick. Take note that your tick labels may interfere with the points displayed in the chart.